# why apache still write files it did have permissions to after I exclude it from the group that has permission when it was running

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, usermod

On the server, I have a file called **upload** and
its state was as follows:

`drwx--x--- 12 bob bob 4096 JUL 20 19:07 upload`

I use this file to be the destination file of the **PHP** function `move_uploaded_file`'s second argument to store the uploaded files.

So in order to get apache this permission to move files from **/tmp** to my **upload**,
I add **apache** to the **bob** group, so it has the permission. **apache** is the user the apache is running as.

But if I exclude **apache** from the group **bob** using **usermod**, I can still upload files which means **apache** still have permissions like it's still in the group but obviously it isn't.

Uploading files will fail only when I

`chmod -R 700 upload`

or whenever I

`service httpd restart`

I don't know where I've missed in this.

Seems to me, `usermod` will only apply permission changes after restarting apache.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, the [usermod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) command only changes the account files

> The usermod command modifies the system account files to reflect the changes that are specified on the command line.

The apache process will be granted it's privileges when it is started, based on the information in the relevant account files, it will retain them till it is restarted.

Comment: then why chmod works? chmod isn't modifying the files to reflect the change?

Comment: @Lucaz: Perhaps you should read some docs on [unix file system permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions), the you'll know the answer to your comment.